# how to click image on main activity in android

Tags: android, fragment

I am using data display on horizontal listview using arrayadapter. Here list item click properly but inside the listview there is image, So how to click that image.

```
public class CArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CModel> {    
    // Here I defined: favourite button

    holder.imgFav = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgFav);
}
```

In MainFragment:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
    hCustomListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, final int position, long arg3) {
            // Working properly
        }

    });
}
```

How do I click imgFav on MainActivity?

Comment: put clicklistener inside adapter for that imageview rather than custom list

Comment: what's the functionality you want to workout onlistview click and image click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom Adapter on Image Click action

```
if(convertView== null){
....
viewHolder.imgFav = (ImageView) convertView .findViewById(R.id.imgFav);
viewHolder.imgFav.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //image click action
                    int pos = (int) v.getTag();

                }
            });
....
} else{
viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}

viewHolder.imgFav.setTag(position);
.....
```